# find command: -or option doesn't work

Tags: find, wildcards, patterns

I want to execute a command for an each file that matches a pattern. But the command that seems to be right, doesn't work for me, I have no idea why.

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.c' -or -name '*.h' -or -name '*.cpp' -exec ls {} \;
$ ls
script.sh  test.c  test.h
```

Comment: Are you just using `-exec ls {} \;` as an example action or actually wanting to do something with it? (don't see what purpose it serves in the above command)

Comment: Yeah, @Bro, I wanted to execute a custom script to a source code files(btw, you may see the one in `ls` output above). The `ls` was chosen just as an example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding the expressions into parentheses as stated in the man page:

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.c' -or -name '*.h' -or -name '*.cpp' \) -exec ls {} \;
```

should work.

Comment: Yeah, this worked! Thank you very much! Btw, I just searched the man page of the `find`; I didn't find anything a brackets. What're you talking about?

Comment: I was talking about the `BSD` man page of `find`, which provides the following example: `find / \( -newer ttt -or -user wnj \) -print` Sorry I was unclear about it.

Comment: That's funny though, that the GNU/Linux manual didn't mention so important thing.

Comment: @YagamyLight The GNU man page uses the more precise word *parenthesis* to refer to parentheses. So does the FreeBSD man page, for that matter.

Comment: @Gilles I found the only mention in GNU manual about a parentheses -- is to force a precedence. In the answer the job of these seems to have nothing to do with the precedence.

Comment: @YagamyLight Operator precedence is exactly what the parentheses are doing here. The `-or` operator has looser precedence than the juxtaposition operator, so parentheses are needed to indicate that the `-or` list is one unit.

Comment: @Gilles hm... I didn't said this, but my code from the topic is works if I remove the part `-or -name '*.cpp'`, so that the code looks like `find . -type f -name '*.c' -or -name '*.h' -exec ls {} \;`. Is this changes a precedence? Or why it was started to work? And btw, I still don't understand, why the precedence here matters? Is this mean that the `find` may work with absolutely identical options differently, because of a precedence and parentheses?

Comment: @YagamyLight Operator precedence is what makes 2+3*4 have the value 14, because it's parsed like 2+(3*4), and not the value 20 like (2+3)*4. If you add parentheses, you aren't calling `find` with identical options. All the `find` commands you posted work, in that they are valid commands, but they do different things (they list different sets of files).

Comment: @Gilles I know what the operator precedence is, though the `find` accepts just an options. Anyway, can you please explain me, in what the sequence the `find` executed these in my case, that it haven't found anything?

Comment: @YagamyLight Some of the options are binary (`-or`, and juxtaposition is also a binary operator) or unary operators (`-not`). I have no idea what sequence you are refering to in your second sentence. This comment discussion is getting really long, I recommend that you read the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#find-Expressions), and if some things still aren't clear, ask a new question.

Comment: @YagamyLight I answered [a similar question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24339320/3076724), which may help you understand this better. In particular, this issue here is your original syntax is treated as `find . (-type f AND -name '*.c') OR (-name '*.h') OR (-name '*.cpp' AND -exec ls {} \;)`

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU find`, you can use `-regex` option:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*\.\(c\|h\|cpp\)' -exec ls {} \;
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the GNU syntax but on BSD this is the correct way to do it with regex: `find -E . -type f -regex '.*(c|h|cpp)$' -exec ls {} \;`

Comment: @Groxxda GNU find supports both. It defaults to Emacs regexps, which have a `\|` operator, unlike FreeBSD, which defaults to BRE.

Comment: I was merely talking about the `.*` vs. `*.`. After testing the command from this answer on GNU find i have verified it's wrong, but my poor reputation won't let me fix it. I don't understand how a not-working answer is up-voted. JIC here is the working GNU find command: `find . -type f -regex '.*\(c\|h\|cpp\)' -exec ls {} \;`

Comment: @Groxxda: Sorry, my mistypo. I will make it more accurry.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `find -D tree . [expr..]` to understand what find does with your original command.

You must understand that the `-type f` and also the `-exec ls ..` expressions are `and`'ed to the rest of the expressions with higher precedence than the `or`s.
So your original command will get parsed into something like this: `(-type f AND -name *.c) OR -name *.h OR (-name *.cpp AND -exec ls)` (note that the or is actually binary and not ternary so `a | b | c` is in fact `(a | b) | c`, but you get the point).
Now you will notice that find does not know what to do except for files matching `*.cpp` as there is no valid statement in the other cases (that's why you may even see a segfault or something similar in the debug output).

I hope this makes it more clear to you why you need the parentheses.